# Training model on custom data

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to try an object detection model on a custom data set. I want it to recognize a specififc piece of metal from my garage. I took like 32 photos and labelled them. The training goes well, but up to 10% loss. After that it goes very slow, so I need to stop it. After that, I implemented the model on camera, but it has no accuracy. Could it be because of the fact that I have only 32 images of the object? I have tried with YoloV2 and Faster RCNN.

Answer (score 0):

It has low probability that your model implemented to a camera has no accuracy because you have only 32 images. 
Anyway before you've had about up to 10% loss (It seems to be about 90% accuracy), so it should work 
 I think the problem is not in the amount of images.
After training your model you need to save the coefficients of model trained. 
Make sure that you implemented model trained, and not you don't use model from scratch

Answer (score 0):

Just labeling will not help in object detection. What you are doing is image classification but expecting results of object detection.

Object detection requires bounding box annotations and changes in the loss function which is to be fed to the model during each backpropagation step.

You need some tools to do data annotations first, then manipulate your Yolov2/Fast-RCNN codes along with the loss function. Train it well and try using Image Augmentations to generate little more images because 32 images are less. In that case, you might end up in a pitfall of getting higher training accuracy but less test accuracy. Training models in fewer images sometimes lead to unexpected overfitting.

Only then you should try to implement using the camera.

Comment: I have followed this tutorial on YouTube and did the same like in the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eFJOGsQ_YTA&t=271s

Comment: If you exactly followed the steps, you should be able to see a bounding box. If not, try lowering the threshold value. 
I suggest you refer the complete tutorial in depth once again.

Comment: I used LabelImg for Images. I am really stuck. I will try with 200-300 images